# Some clarity on how to use View Models with MVC and ModelBinding please

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am getting confused about the use of ViewModels in an edit form where one of the properties is the editable entity ie

```
ViewModel
   Entity
   Actions
```

The model desclaration at the top of the View page:

```
   @model MyProject.Models.ViewModel
```

Not

```
   @model MyProject.Models.Entity
```

So what is the best way to represent the Entity Property which is the one that needs updating. I first started making a variable out of it.

```
Entity myEntity = ViewModel.Entity;
```

So each form element edit field might be represented by:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => myEntity.Name)
```

However what happens with the Model Binding parameters in the post action?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Entity myEntity)

            db.Entities.Attach(myEntity);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

So this question is really about how to deal with editable property objects in a ViewModel as opposed to a specific Entity Object that could be passed in as the Model which is straight forward.

Answer most likely simple.

Huge thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Feedback on how to reference domain objects from a ViewModel in a View. I have found that if I reference them directly in the lambda expresions, then model binding works fine as it can use the derived ids to navigate around the returned ViewModel. If one use a local variable in the View then this variable name is then used in the Id which then breaks the ViewModel Model binding mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST action should take the view model as parameter, not the domain model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
```

then you should use the ID of this viewModel to retrieve the corresponding domain model from the database that needs to be updated. And then update the properties of this domain model from the view model. Finally persist the domain model back to the database.

Comment: Hi Darin, Thanks for this. Have I written my EditFor lines correctly in using a local variable for the Entity? Also I note from your answer that it seems that one needs to explicitly map the relevant form properties to the domain properties rather than use modelbinding? Is Modelbinding reserved for domain Models and not ViewModels?

Comment: No, model binding will work just the same way, except that it will bind the values to the view model (which is the correct approach). It is up to you (or to a framework such as AutoMapper) to convert this view model to a domain model. That's not the responsibility of the model binder.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the clarification. Can I trouble you to comment on my EditFor code lines. Should I write them against a local variable ie "E=>myEntity.Name" or against the Model directly ie "E=>Model.Entity.Name"

Comment: The lambda expression should not contain external references. In your case you wrote `model => myEntity.Name` but it is not clear where this `myEntity` variable is defined. In the lambda expression there should only be the `model` variable appearing. For example: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)`.

Comment: Darin, "myEntity" is defined at the top of the View Page in a @{} block. If I did how you suggested then I guess the lambda would look like "@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Entity.Name)" as the Entity domain object is a property of the VIewModel.

Comment: What's the point of using a view model if all that this view model will have is a property holding your domain model? A view model should be a flattened representation of one or more domain models containing only the logic/properties that are required by the specific view. If you are going to stuff your domain model as a property to the view model then you don't really need this view model. It's not bringing you any benefit in this case.

Comment: I am using a View Model since it is part of a Wizard Workflow to acquire different datasets. One aspect of the VM are the Workflow steps etc and the other is the domain object that is being updated. I guess I could have kept the Model to the domain Object and used a ViewBag to store the Wizard Step information like StepName, Action etc.